Hexagonal Architecture + Domain Driven Design. How to perform a correct implementation?
Currently, I am trying to implement these two architectures together with Java and Spring (although technology shouldn't matter I think).
But I'm encountering problems getting them to work together.
I understand that my application should have a structure with 2 zones (inside and outside the hexagon) and 3 layers:
Domain: Entities that should be self-contained with their own functionality, Repositories, ValueObjects, Factories, Events, etc. This layer is the center of the hexagon.
Application: Where the ports should be found. I've also seen that this is where REST or "input" adapters are typically implemented. This layer is at the edge of the hexagon.
Infrastructure: the implementation of the output ports, where external libraries and frameworks should already be used. This layer is outside the hexagon.
But this raises several questions for me. In the examples that I have been fiding ( here, here or here) i find adapters implemented in the application layer or in the infrastructure layer, depending on whether they are input or output.
I don't understand the reason for this implementation, when the adapters are supposed to be outside the hexagon, and therefore should go in the infrastructure layer.
What do repositories and domain services do? Shouldn't these be in the application layer as interfaces, and infrastructure should implement them? After all, all the logic should go in the entity.
Right now I have this structure (after following several guides and reviewing some repositories on GitHub):
Shop (Base Module)
Shop-Domain (Submodule)
    src/main/java
    ├─── net.test.sell.domain
    │    └─── error (exceptions related)
    │    └─── model (Entities, ValueObjects, Events, etc...)
    ├─── net.test.workers.domain
    ....
 
Shop-Application (Submodule)
    src/main/java
    ├─── net.test.sell.aplication
    │    └─── ports
    |          └─── input (implementation of use cases)
               └─── output (interfaces for infrastructure submodule)
    │    └─── use_cases (interfaces)
    ├─── net.test.workers.application

Shop-Infrastructure (Submodule)
    src/main/java
    ├─── net.test.sell.infrastructure
    │    └─── database
    |          └─── adapters (implementation output interfaces)
    │    └─── rest_api(interfaces)
    |          └─── controllers (just REST Controllers)
    ├─── net.test.workers.infrastructure
    ...

I also have some questions regarding the most appropriate folder structure for this architecture.
Why do InputPorts use UseCases and OutputPorts are interfaces that are later implemented in infrastructure?
Is it a good practice to implement each small UseCase in a separate interface? Or can everything be done in one?
Finally. What is the correct naming convention for the different projects and packages?
Thanks in advance!

"Why are adapters typically implemented in the application layer or in the infrastructure layer, depending on whether they are input or output?" Says who? Please cite a source.

@candied_orange updated with examples/sources for this question

Thank you for the update. Consider this: if I claimed that the typical human was red headed and backed up the claim by showing 3 pictures of red heads do you think I've made a very good case for the claim? Or would it be better if I was citing a source that was actually dealing with the issue of how typical it was?

you were right ,I wanted to say that, "in the examples I have been finding, I find this structure, which I do not understand.", also i edit another time.

If those three are all you could find say that. If these are just three of 101 that you’ve looked at say that. If all 101 show the same thing, say that. It’s what you’re not saying that’s killing me.

Let's set some terms in this response first:
DDD - an analysis method (along with some general design guidance)
Hexagonal - an architecture pattern.
We're analyzing our problem space using DDD and implementing the solution using a hexagonal architecture pattern.  DDD will help us find the different contexts and the entities - both those unique to a domain and those shared across domains.  If we're using Java, this is good information for how we scope our components.  We can have a package hierarchy that represents our domain/sub-domain/entity decomp for the things private to a domain. We can have other hierarchy for the shared core and another for the platform-y stuff we want to commonize/standardize on. The latter two can be imported for use.
Obvious, but worth mentioning - businesses change.  So, the more semantic content you capture in your modeling, the more work in the future when things change. Business strategies change less frequently, so you can sometimes get insight from the strategy on what might or might not change in the future. ex: Mercedes is unlikely to truly sell a Yugo-like car anytime soon. (hello, C-class owners!)
OK..as others have pointed out, there's not THE WAY to implement a hexagonal architecture.  That's on purpose since the context creates forces that help evaluate the trade-offs of different approaches.  One often-used approach is to define the port as an interface and then implement it (the adapter) as a concrete class. You wire it in using dependency injection so you can switch out the adapter for a different one (e.g., move from postgress to neo4j or MQ to Kafka) easily.
Another way to integrate is to use reflection.  This might be helpful if you need to alter the behavior while the system is running.  There's the obvious downside.  The gist is that in-bound or out-bound, the contract is an interface and the invocation is via an adapter. By packaging these details out separately, you are now open to changing them without impacting the core business logic.
Last, use cases vs interfaces.  The above hints at the answer. Let's assume the domain is my personal life.  My girlfriend lies within my domain, although I have encountered one or two who were confused about that. Let's also suppose I have a common core entity that notifies me when events occur, like Xmas, birthdays, etc. When "we" are being called, an external client is invoking some function we offer (interface). It's our anniversary? Buy-card. She left me? Trash-card. etc. This call is happening in the context of some use case that's being executed. Typically, we don't want to instantiate each use case. That will lead to very brittle code. Use cases are instantiated by passing variables into orchestration or choreography that model some broader scenario (review Schank's concepts of scripts and conceptual dependency), like buying a  gift . When we're calling out, we're typically invoking some kind of support function to complete our contract. How many days before my girlfriends b-day? (negative what?! oh no..) Skip Victoria's Secret; what sweaters are in stock? Do you have flowers? like, big bunches of them? Cards? Munson's chocolate?  We don't want to be coupled to the thing-y that has the answer. Late or not, I'm still looking for a deal. Uncle Lou's Attic chocolate? $0.79/lb? Sounds yummy. Hello, Lou?
So, the term "use case" is related to the context, not the implementation.  That client that's calling our function did so through their adapter. (If my reminder had only come through Kafka and not email into my junk folder...) "They" (and we have no idea who "they" are) are just telling me to buy a gift.  The fact that it was delivered through freaking email... well, hmm... kind of a shared flaw.
We are doing the same - invoking a function (or many.. damn dating is expensive) without knowing much about the listener except for the contract. The listener doesn't know the use case. They only know I want to buy stuff.. lots and lots of it. So, we "know" the interface but abstract the instantiation of the call so it can be updated easily. Thus, the packaging. In a well-designed architecture, the non-functionals (latency, message loss, idempotence) are taken into consideration and the mechanisms for communication and choreography or orchestration are implemented accordingly.
Hmm, on second thought, I might need to drive to the store while I blame my poor timing on a porch pirate architect. Phew. Crisis solved.
If you want to get some more insight on how to wire Hexagonal in a flexible way, take a look at Microsoft's JHipster Lite and the code it generates. Not perfect, but it'll give you a starting point for how you might want to do it on your own.

I'm sorry to say that there is no one silver bullet when designing software. There is no "correct" way to do anything. Everything is a trade-off between different aspects of the system, like function, maintainability, security, etc.
Doing Hexagonal Architecture and DDD (or any other patterns for that matter) just for the fun of it, will probably not end well. I.e. not result in a maintainable system.
Specifically, separating things based on their technology (i.e. horizontally), instead of functionality (i.e. vertically) will lead you to have to modify each of these layers and projects for almost every feature request. Which is not good.
Unless there is a specific, immediate reason for you to do this (like organizational or technological constraints) you shouldn't do this. If you're wondering why something is the way it is, you probably don't have a need for that thing to be that way.
I'd recommend you just express your domain plainly with classes/interfaces/methods as best as you can. Try to have the least amount of publicly available internal state, i.e. getters. Ideally none or countable on one hand. And then go from there, introduce structure once you can find fairly independent parts of functionality. Grow the architecture iteratively and organically, instead of preemptively and forcibly.
I know this potentially sets you back to square one, but you asked. ;)

I totally understand that there are no magic or perfect solutions, and that every problem has its own specifics.
But if I need to learn this, and the proposed solution is: "if you do it 'for fun,' etc...." then how else should I go about learning? Of course, this isn't an ideal scenario, but I still need to try out some kind of PoC to gain experience and learn.
As for the rest of your post, I really appreciate the advice, and I'll definitely give my projects another look, especially applying those ideas about separating things vertically or horizontally.
Thanks again for your response

What would make an implementation correct isn't doing what you're told. It's gracefully avoiding what you were warned about.

... Alistair Cockburn, the inverter of the Hexagonal Architecture, he made it very clear that this architecture style has nothing to do with a package structure at all.
tbuss - How to do the package structure in a Ports and Adapters architecture

There are things that impose a structure, like maven, but at a certain point there is definitely some flexibility.
DDD has it's bounded contexts, domains, and aggregates but even those don't completely dictate your package structure. They just represent some needs your package structure must accommodate.

folder-by-feature structure is superior to folder-by-layer structure in the majority of cases
Stack Overflow - Should we use 'package by feature' structure with DDD?

DDD leaves us a lot of packaging flexibility. If you're looking to be told exactly how to do it you need advice from more than DDD.
Personally I favor package by feature most of the time. But that's just me. There are many implementation examples you can follow. Just not in those books. And that's deliberate. Once you're creating an implementation many choices have to be made that were never in the scope of the book.
